# Return how many times ALL elements in list X appear in the sublists of a list of lists D only if ALL elements in another list Y do not appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, variables

I have the following dataset:

```
D=[[A,B,D,E],[B,C,E],[A,B,D,E],[A,B,C,E],[A,B,C,D,E],[B,C,D]]
```

And I need to find a way in which to get how many times an element `X` appears on a list only if another element `Y` doesn't appear, that is, `sup_X¬Y`.

For example, `sup_E¬C`, means the amount of times where `E` appears in a list where `C` does not appear. In this case, this condition is satisfied in positions `D[0]` and `D[2]`, so the answer should be 2.

In another example, `sup_E¬AD` means the amount of times where `E` appears in a list where `A` and `D` does not appear. This condition is satisfied in positions `D[1]`, so the answer should be 1

I have this code that lets me find the amount of times an element `X` appears,

```
sup_X=(sum(1 for x in D if set(X) <= set(x) ))
```

for example, the element ['A','B'] appears 4 times in the Dataset, in `D[0]`,`D[2]`,`D[3]`,`D[4]`

and tried to apply the same logic where, but I haven't been able to do it

Comment: can you test the one-liner I have provided? Also, I believe there is a typo here: "In another example, sup_E¬AD means the amount of times where E appears in a list where `A` and `B` does not appear." I think you meant to say: "... where `A` and `D` does not appear." I am editing but feel free to roll-back if I'm incorrect.

Comment: I have also changed the title to `Return how many times ALL elements in list X appear in the sublists of a list of lists D only if ALL elements in another list Y do not appear` to better reflect the question. Keep in mind that a list can be length of one, i.e. contain one string, but I think you need to normalize to lists rather than lists versus strings if there is a potential that X AND Y can each have more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would isolate the sub-lists that match the criteria first:

```
>>> D=[['A','B','D','E'],['B','C','E'],['A','B','D','E'],['A','B','C','E'],['A','B','C','D','E'],['B','C','D']]
>>> res = [i for i in D if 'E' in i and 'C' not in i]
>>> len(res)
2
```

If you only care about the sum then you can do:

```
>>> res = sum(1 for i in D if 'E' in i and 'C' not in i)
>>> res
2
```

UPDATE 1: Based on comment (2nd example)

Things get a bit too complex to do in a 1-liner I think, so what about the following:

```
>>> def my_filter(appear, not_appear):
...     res = []
...     for lst in D:
...         is_ok = True
...         for ap in appear:
...             if ap not in lst:
...                 is_ok = False
...         for nap in not_appear:
...             if nap in lst:
...                 is_ok = False
...         if is_ok:
...             res.append(lst)
...     
...     return res
... 
>>> res = my_filter({'E'}, {'A', 'D'})
>>> len(res)
1
>>> res
[['B', 'C', 'E']]
```

Again, if you are only interested in count/sum you can modify the res to be an int and to `res += 1` instead of append

UPDATE 2:

A more compact version would be the following but I find it hard to read and I would not prefer it:

```
>>> appear = {'E'}
>>> not_appear = {'A', 'D'}
>>> res = [
    lst
    for lst in D 
    if (
        all(map(lambda x: x in lst, appear))
        and all(map(lambda x: x not in lst, not_appear))
    )
]
>>> len(res)
1
```

Comment: but what if I need to look for more than one element? Like in my second example

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[['A','B','D','E'],['B','C','E'],['A','B','D','E'],['A','B','C','E'],['A','B','C','D','E'],['B','C','D']]

X='E'
Y='C'

print( sum(X in l and Y not in l for l in lst) )
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `return` line is the one liner list comprehension logic you are looking for. Please note that you should normalize `x` and `y` variable to list format if x and/or y could be lists, even if the list only contains one string:

```
D=[['A','B','D','E'],['B','C','E'],['A','B','D','E'],['A','B','C','E'],['A','B','C','D','E'],['B','C','D']]

def f(l, x, y):
    return sum([1 for sl in l if all([True if x1 in sl and y1 not in sl
                                      else False for x1 in x for y1 in y])])


print(f(D,['E'],['C']))
print(f(D,['E'],['B','D']))
print(f(D,['E'],['A','D']))

2
0
1
```